# Trying to insert values into a table where some values will be select statements whereas others will be hardcoded

Tags: sql, sql-insert

My select into query would start like this:

insert into camrule (HCHARGECODE, htenant, dtfrom, dtto, IESTIMATETYPE, destimated, imaxpermo)

My hchargecode would be a hardcoded value of 174, my htenant would be based on a select statment (ex. select htenant from tableX), and so on.  How can I hardcode the columns and have the other values from the select statments added to my camrule table?

Also, this is for multiple rows, not just a single row to be inserted.

I've tried creating a temp table with the hardcoded values, but am getting an error.  I was hoping I could insert the columns from this temp table into my camrule table.

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxORm.png)

Answer (score 1):

Use the Values keyword to get this done...

```
insert into camrule (HCHARGECODE, htenant, dtfrom, dtto, IESTIMATETYPE, destimated, imaxpermo)
values(174,(select htenant from tableX), and so on...
```

This way allows you to select values from different tables, as opposed to just adding hard-coded columns to a Select statement from a single source table.

Comment: This is the query I'm using but am getting an error saying subquery returned more than 1 value.  I'm trying to insert multiple rows, my "select scode from #temp7" has over 100 records.

insert into camrule (HCHARGECODE, htenant, dtfrom, dtto, IESTIMATETYPE, destimated, imaxpermo) 
values ('174',(select scode from #temp7), (select dtfrom from #temp7), (select dtto from #temp7), '2', (select destimated from #temp7), '0')

Comment: You're really going to have to use your knowledge of the larger RDBMS to link the subqueries (those select statements inside the value clause) so that they return one and only one row - and that it's the right row each time. There's no practical way for anyone on this site to opine on that without that in-depth knowledge.

Comment: In other words, add a Where clause to each of those subqueries that ensure that the correct, single row is returned. If that's impossible then you need to implement @TheImpaler's recommendation, using table joins to shape the right source resultset.

Answer (score 0):

You can do as simple as:

```
insert into camrule (
  HCHARGECODE, htenant, dtfrom, dtto, 
  IESTIMATETYPE, destimated, imaxpermo
)
select
  174, htenant, dtfrom, dtto, 
  IESTIMATETYPE, destimated, imaxpermo 
from tableX
```

Comment: If you copy your SQL as text we can help you fix it.

Comment: But each column will be pulling from a different table, and your example would only work for one row to be inserted into the camrule table.  The htenant column will be a select statement that pulls 860 rows, same for the other columns that are not hardcoded.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would help:

```
insert into camrule (
  HCHARGECODE, htenant, dtfrom, dtto, 
  IESTIMATETYPE, destimated, imaxpermo
)
select
  174, htenant, dtfrom, dtto, 
  IESTIMATETYPE, destimated, imaxpermo 
from tableX
```

If all the data required except the hardcoded ones are in tableX. If they are in different tables then something like this would help:

```
insert into camrule (
  HCHARGECODE, htenant, dtfrom, dtto, 
  IESTIMATETYPE, destimated, imaxpermo
)
select
  174, x.htenant, x.dtfrom, x.dtto, 
  y.IESTIMATETYPE, y.destimated, z.imaxpermo 
from tableX x <join queries for tableX x, tableY y, tableZ z>
```